# How to have Spring ContextConfiguration load both from XML and from JavaConfig

Tags: spring-test

From what I've read of the Spring @ContextConfiguration annotation, it's possible to load multiple XML context files, or multiple JavaConfig classes.  What I need is to load from one XML context file and one class.  All the examples I've seen either load all XML, or all classes, but not both.

I'm trying to do this because I want my test class, which is just there to verify expected Spring wiring, to load my default applicationContext.xml file (presently just a copy stored in "src/test/resources, and trying to figure out how to directly specify the default one) along with a JavaConfig class that specifies some JNDI resources that need to be available.  For the purposes of my test, I only need to set those JNDI resources to dummy strings, but I'd really like to specify them in an inline static class instead of an external XML file, because my tests are going to have to verify that some settings are equal to those dummy strings, and it's more maintainable if both the values and the checks are in the same file.

What I have so far, and what I've tried, can be illustrated with this:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(value = {"/testApplicationContext.xml", "/testResources.xml"})
//@ContextHierarchy({
//    @ContextConfiguration("/testApplicationContext.xml"),
//    @ContextConfiguration(classes = SpringWiringTest.Config.class)
//})
@TestPropertySource(properties = { "env = tomcat", "doNotifications = false" })
public class SpringWiringTest {
```

And this at the end of the class:

```
@Configuration
public static class Config {
    @Bean public String uslDatasourcesList() { return "abc"; }
    @Bean public String atgDatasourcesList() { return "abc"; }
    @Bean public String uslTableNamePrefixsList() { return "abc"; }
    @Bean public String atgTableNamePrefixsList() { return "abc"; }
    @Bean public String doNotifications() { return "false"; }
    @Bean public DataSource abc() { return new DriverManagerDataSource(); }
}
```

If I comment out the first @ContextConfiguration and comment back in the @ContextHierarchy block, I get an error like this:

> Error creating bean with name 'uslDatasourcesList': Invocation of init
>   method failed; nested exception is
>   javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in
>   environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an
>   application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial

**Update**:

Using the guideline of picking either JavaConfig or XML as the "entry point" to configuration, here are some modified excerpts that show what I'm trying:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration
//@ContextConfiguration(value = {"file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml", "/testResources.xml"})
@TestPropertySource(properties = { "env = tomcat", "doNotifications = false" })
public class SpringWiringTest {
    ...
    @BeforeClass
    public static void setup() throws Exception {
        SimpleNamingContextBuilder  builder = SimpleNamingContextBuilder.emptyActivatedContextBuilder();
        DataSource  ds  = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        builder.bind("java:comp/env/abc", ds);
    }
    ...
    @Configuration
    @ImportResource("file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml")
    public static class Config {
        @Bean public String uslDatasourcesList() { return "abc"; }
        @Bean public String atgDatasourcesList() { return "abc"; }
        @Bean public String uslTableNamePrefixsList() { return "abc"; }
        @Bean public String atgTableNamePrefixsList() { return "abc"; }
        @Bean public String doNotifications() { return "false"; }
        @Bean public DataSource abc() { return new DriverManagerDataSource(); }
    }
}
```

When I run my test, the bottom "Caused by" in the exception says this:

> Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name
>   [uslDatasourcesList] not bound; 1 bindings: [java:comp/env/abc]

In the alternate version, using the commented-out "@ContextConfiguration" (and commenting out the Config class and its annotations), this error does not occur.

Note that this the meat of my "testResources.xml" file:

```
<bean id="uslDatasourcesList" class="java.lang.String"> <constructor-arg value="abc"/> </bean>
<bean id="atgDatasourcesList" class="java.lang.String"> <constructor-arg value="abc"/> </bean>
<bean id="uslTableNamePrefixList" class="java.lang.String"> <constructor-arg value="abc"/> </bean>
<bean id="atgTableNamePrefixList" class="java.lang.String"> <constructor-arg value="abc"/> </bean>
<bean id="doNotifications" class="java.lang.String"> <constructor-arg value="false"/> </bean>

<bean id="abc" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
</bean>
```

Note that the bean mentioned in the error message, "uslDatasourcesList" is defined in both versions, but it's not working in the version with JavaConfig and XML mixed.

It almost appears that the beans in the "@ImportResource" annotation are evaluated on their own, before the beans declared in the JavaConfig class are merged into it.

Answer (score 0):

This is clearly documented in the Spring Reference Manual in the section named [Mixing XML, Groovy scripts, and annotated classes](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#testcontext-ctx-management-mixed-config).

In summary, ...

> ... you will have to pick one as the entry point, and that one will have to include or import the other.

Thus, the following should *hopefully* solve your problem.

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration
@TestPropertySource(properties = { "env = tomcat", "doNotifications = false" })
public class SpringWiringTest {

    // ...

    @Configuration
    @ImportResource({"/testApplicationContext.xml", "/testResources.xml"})
    static class Config {
        // ...
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes, I saw that section, and I tried something along those lines, but I couldn't get it to work. I will now try harder, as it appears to be the only way to do this.  I'll update the post with details of this attempt.